# Does Ubuntu 1604 LTS support Intel 2011-3 CPU and the X99 support chips?

Tags: system-installation

The question is fully stated in the title.  There have been articles stating that Ubuntu has updated their code to support the 2011-3 CPU.  I have not found a statement saying that 1604 is that specificallly updated version

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware compatibility question.

Comment: Just to be a pain, I don't agree with that link to the answer, it basically says "try it a find out with a live cd", X99 and 2011-v3 are very expensive workstation level chipset, you'll be dropping around £600 minimum just to see if it works. I had this exact question which is why I found the thread in the first place, it may be a dupe but link a better question if you can find one

Comment: @Adam In general "Is Ubuntu compatible with my hardware?" is suitable for questions about the compatibility of "my hardware", the purpose being to block thousands of questions about the compatibility of every single hardware device **except for hardware that the OP does not already own**, however the possibility that the OP does not already own the hardware that he is asking about is speculative. Let us assume that the OP does not already own the hardware that he is asking about. That makes the question into a shopping recommendation question which is off-topic at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @karel thanks for the clarification, that makes sense. Not sure why my answer how now been deleted though